# Native crash trying to execute SQLite update

Tags: android, sqlite, crash

I'm trying to increment the value of an integer column in all rows of a SQLite table. Let's say the table name is `items` and the column name is `value`. The code looks like this:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = getDatabase();
db.execSQL("update items set value = (value + 1)");
```

The code is running in a unit test, and the entire test suite halts completely with the following message:

> Test failed to run to completion. Reason: 'Instrumentation run failed
>   due to 'Native crash''. Check device logcat for details

[Here is the entire crash dump from logcat.](http://pastebin.com/e3VP4P0q)

I have verified in a SQLite shell that the update statement above does indeed work as written and will increment the value of the column. I've also tried these variations, resulting each time with the same crash:

```
// variation 1
String sql = "update items set value = ?";
String[] sqlArgs = new String[]{ "(value + 1)" };
db.execSQL(sql, sqlArgs); // crashes

// variation 2
SQLiteStatement statement = db.compileStatement();
statement.execute(); // crashes

// variation 3
// Near as I can tell, below is what execSql does under the hood
SQLiteStatement statement = db.compileStatement();
statement.executeUpdateDelete(); // crashes
```

Has anyone run into something like this before? How can I execute an update statement like the one above without crashing?

**EDIT**

This crash appears to happen only within an Android JUnit test. In an actual running application, the `execSQL()` call with the update statement above executes successfully. I'd still like to know what causes it, but at least production code appears not to be affected by it...

Comment: Is is possible your database file is corrupted?

Comment: @laalto: That's an interesting thought and I won't rule it out, but I very much doubt that's the case. The test harness clears and creates the database anew with each run. I also ran it on more than one device plus an emulator, and it's hard to believe the database would become corrupt on every run on every device.

Comment: Yes, something systematically wrong. Anything special in `getDatabase()`? Also in variation 1 the args are wrong (you can bind only literals and not expressions) but that wouldn't cause the crash.

Comment: No, it just returns the SQLiteDatabase being used for these tests.

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the same problem with my app.
In my app we have around 30-40 packages and we tested each and every class together.
The test cases are failing in between randomly giving below error:

Test failed to run to completion. Reason: 'Instrumentation run failed due to 'Native crash''. Check device logcat for details

Its a memory Issue while executing the test cases together for all the test classes you create.
So, just override the `onTearDown()` method in each test class and release the memory by nulling the objects used in that test class.

For Example:

`protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
      super.tearDown();
      mActivity = null;
      mInstance = null;
}`

where `mActivity` and `mInstance` are the Instance variable used by all the test methods.

This overriding `tearDown()` and relealing object solved my problem.